# Load-balancing per network port?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, cloud

Theoretically there are:

- client
- LB
- SERVER A
- SERVER B

**Question**: Is there a load-balancer solution (either by software or payed in the cloud) that can redirect the "clients" to "SERVER A" or "SERVER B" based on what network port did they connect to to the LB?

If software, probably there is a solution to have firewall rules on the LB, but I am mainly searching for a payed solution, ex.: AWS, GCP or Azure can do this kind of LBing to a SERVER which is not in their DCs?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean calls reverse proxy. Both AWS and Google Cloud offer similar features in their Load Balancer services.

- On Google Cloud you can look at [URL maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#url-map-components)
- On AWS you can look to Application Load Balancer. Also, take a look at [How do I achieve path-based routing on an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb/)

Anyway, bear in mind that technically speaking, Load Balancer and path-based or port-base routing are different things, although it's been implemented as a Load Balancer feature.

Load Balancer aims to monitor targets and redirect requests only to healthy ones.

Path-based or port-based routing aims to redirect different kinds of requests to different groups of targets.

Comment: many thanks for the answer! But I think I will buy the cheapest VM somewhere that has a good SLA and create a firewall rule :D and update the firewall rule with a script if health probes say